# SELECT data from multiple tables PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get data from multiple tables to build a notifications feed.

I have 3 tables: **users**, **user_notification** and **user_comments**

When I click on the icon to check the notifications, I want to display as a dropdown only the new ones, so in the **user_notification** table I have the rows **"status"**, **id_from** and **id_owner** which can be **"new"** or **"old"**, that way I know what to retrieve, but then my problem comes when I need to get from those notifications, the info about who was it and be able to display the for instance, the profile picture, username, comment_id, etc.

This is the HTML I am trying to get:

```
while ($row_notification = $result_load_notifications->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo '<li class="dropdown-item">
                    <img src="'.$row_notification["avatar"].'" class="avatar-feed" alt="'.$row_notification["name"].'" /><p><strong>'.$row_notification["name"].'</strong> new <a href="https://sample.com/user/'.$_SESSION['alias'].'/#comment-'.$row_notification["id_comment"].'">comment</a> notification.<br>
                    <time class="date-post" datetime="'.$row_notification["date"].'"></time></p>
                    </li>';
            echo '<li class="dropdown-divider"></li>';

        }
```

And this is the PHP/Mysqli I thought could work but didn't:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    user_notification n,
    users u,
    user_comments c
WHERE
    n.status='new'
    AND
    n.id_owner=$session_id
    AND
    u.id_user=n.id_from
    AND
    c.id_owner=n.id_owner
```

In PHP:

```
$load_notifications = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * user_notification n, users u, user_comments c WHERE n.status='new' AND n.id_owner=$session_id AND u.id_user=n.id_from AND c.id_owner=n.id_owner");
```

That code just does not work, am I doing something wrong? (I am not an expert) am I missing a relation between tables?

Any tip would be appreciate it,
Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT *  FROM  user_notification n, ....`

Comment: Your SQL is invalid, you aren't specifying the `FROM` clause. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection: **Never use string concatenation or string interpolation to generate SQL!** *Always use parameterized queries!*

Comment: What about it is not working? You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: Also, using `SELECT *` is a bad idea in production code. You should always explicitly name the columns you want to retrieve.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I edited the SQL to add the FROM, was my mistake, sorry. I am actually using prepared statements, just did it this way for a fast writting. @aynber

Answer (score 0):

I could finally solve my problem, retriving data step by step to understand how this work and ended up with this code (not sure if it is a good practice but it worked):

```
SELECT 
u.name, u.avatar, c.id_comment, c.date 
FROM user_notification n, users u, user_comments c 
WHERE n.id_owner = ? 
AND n.notification_status = ? 
AND u.id_user = n.id_from 
AND c.id_user= n.id_from 
AND c.id_owner = n.id_owner
```